# Andengine Traffic game: moving sprites along path on map

Tags: java, andengine

I'm developing simple traffic educational game, like [*"Allianz Křižovatky"*](https://market.android.com/details?id=cz.allianz.krizovatky.android). When the player taps on a car sprite, it should start to move with the other cars. If the player made a mistake in choosing a car, a collision happens.

I decided to use AndEngine for this game, because I have time limitations in developing it. How do I make the car automatically move along a specified path, with smooth turns? How would I specify this path on a map?

Answer (score 3):

If you already know the path then to make it move smoothly you would apply a [low-pass filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter) to the actual movement. A simple low-pass filter that might work for you is the [weighted moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average).

For example, instead of snapping the car directly to the path like this:

```
car.x = pathNode.x
car.y = pathNode.y
```

You would only move the car partway to where the next node is:

```
car.x = car.x + (pathNode.x - car.x) * 0.8
car.y = car.y + (pathNode.y - car.y) * 0.8
```

This gives up some accuracy to smooth out sharp turns over time. You will have to play around with the weight (0.8 in this case) until it looks good.